# Validate whole number (allowing trailing zeros)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

How do you check if a string is a whole number and allowing for both "1" and "1.0"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a regex, you could use something like:

```
/^\d+(\.0*)?$/
```

This checks for a sequence of one or more digits, followed optionally by a `.` and zero or more trailing `0`.

Comment: This will match `1.`, swap * with +

Comment: Why is `1.` disallowed? The question doesn't state either way.

Comment: Well, I guess the requirements are open ended enough. I've just never written a number that way, do people use that notation?

Comment: @TheZ Several languages' syntax allow `1.` for floating-point numbers, if that's worth anything to you. I do agree, it does look odd at first!

Answer (score 1):

I first considered `validates_numericality_of :your_attribute_here, :only_integer => true`, but it allows no decimal places.

You can use

```
validates_format_of :your_attribute, :with => /\A\d+(\.0+)?\Z/
```

Note the `\A` and `\Z` here. If you use `^` and `$`, it will only match for lines, allowing values like `"1.0\nBLAAAAH"`.